# Representation in the complex plane.

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Determine the set of representations in the complex plane for which:
(a) $\frac{z-1}{z+1}$ is a real number;
(b) $\frac{z-1}{z+1}$ is a pure imaginary number.

Answer (score 2):

Let $z=a+bi$ where $a\in\Bbb R,b\in\Bbb R$. Then

$$\begin{align}
\frac{z-1}{z+1} &= \frac{a+bi-1}{a+bi+1} \\
  &= \frac{(a-1+bi)(a+1-bi)}{(a+1+bi)(a+1-bi)} \\
  &= \frac{a^2-(1-bi)^2}{(a+1)^2-(bi)^2} \\
  &= \frac{(a^2+b^2-1)+2bi}{(a+1)^2+b^2}
\end{align}$$

That denominator is a real number. So, the fraction is a real number if and only if the expression is defined and the imaginary part of the numerator, $2b$, is zero, i.e. $b=0$. So for question $(a)$, $z$ must be a real number not equal to $-1$. The "set of representations in the complex plane" is the real number line with a "hole" at $-1$.

The fraction is a pure imaginary number if and only if the expression is defined and the real part of the numerator, $a^2+b^2-1$, is zero, i.e. $a^2+b^2=1$. So for question $(b)$, $z$ is on the unit circle but not equal to $-1$. Or, stated differently, the modulus $|z|$ equals $1$ but $z$ is not $-1$. The "set of representations in the complex plane" is the circle centered at the origin with radius $1$ with a "hole" at $-1$.

Answer (score 0):

$z-1=k(z+1)$ , $k$ Real so $z-1=kz+k$, so $z(1-k)=k+1$, so $z=\frac {k+1}{1-k}$, $k \in\mathbb R $ (but of course, $k \neq 1$) Can you do the other one? What is the form of a pure imaginary number?

Comment: Right, just edited.